# Is using a numeric value instead a predefinied constant bad practice?

Tags: php, pdo, coding-style, constants

So this is a pretty simple example:

```
$sth    = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Is it considered as bad practice by using the value of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead the constant itself?

If you write a lot of code this would be a bit faster (of cause not only in this example)

```
$sth    = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(2);
```

So instead using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` - just `2` which is the value of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

The most popular usage I've seen yet, was `error_reporting(24567)` instead `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED)` *(or similar used)*

---

I know that other code maintainers would have difficulties to understand this code. But are there any disadvantages?

Comment: The constant changes per version and system. Using the constant is the only way to ensure constant behavior.

Comment: Using constants is also a whole lot more readable than magic numbers. What exactly does "fetch all 2" mean, do you know off the top of your head? Saving keystrokes is not the goal in programming.

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster though? The constant is used to make your code more readable, but it's converted to the numeric value at compile time, so it executes at run-time without any additional performance overhead

Comment: @chris85 - it's not a constant. It's the value.

Comment: @bassxzero Actually the constants in my example are the same across all versions: https://3v4l.org/1aH3U

Comment: You could define the default fetch mode in PDO with a special connection option: PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.

Comment: I would really like to hear the thinking behind this question; how can code written according to the manual be "bad practice"?

Comment: @deceze According to the manual you should use the constants, of cause. I don't know any examples across the manual which use numeric value instead a suitable constant. My question is just - *Beside the worse readability* - If it would be ok to use numeric values?

Comment: @CodeBrauer purely coincidence and should not be counted on.

Comment: @bassxzero thank you. Of cause this could be the case someday.

Answer (score 2):

> If you write a lot of code

...then you are doing something wrong. *Programming* stands for writing as little code as possible. Example. Write the following code **once**

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and then write just

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

without any parameter at all either a constant or a number.

Not to mention that

> I know that other code maintainers would have difficulties to understand this code.

this reason alone is more than enough

Comment: First of all, thank you. Just to be clear: I always use the constants. Maybe my example wasn't the best, thanks for the better solution anyway :). I posted this question mainly because I have to maintain a lot of code that isn't mine... And I often see that "numeric values" in other people code. I already thought that this is a bad practice - I just wanted to ask this on SO, because I wanted to read some more opinions. (Maybe I was wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered as bad practice by using the value of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead the constant itself?

Yes, it is bad practice

> I know that other code maintainers would have difficulties to understand this code. But are there any disadvantages?

Yes, PHP *MIGHT* change the value associated with the constant in the future. - (a slight modification on what [bassxzero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670424/is-using-a-numeric-value-instead-a-predefinied-constant-bad-practice#comment80289272_46670424) said)

**Best Practices** are not about ease of *writing* code.  If they were, we would all use them by default.  They are about ease of *maintanence* of code.  They are about building your code on a firm foundation, so it can weather the storm.

Also, conceptually you are not *really* passing the numeric value of 2 as a parameter, you are passing the answer of "Fetch an Associative Array" *represented* by the number 2.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and you explanation. I just was curious, espaccialy because I could find any questions or hints about this. I know it should be common sense, to use it – As already commented on the other answer, I see this in other people code and wanted to have some opinions on this.